# Creating an alternating array method in java, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that takes two int [] as arguments and returns a new int [] which is filled in an alternating sequence from the two given arrays. Ex: given arrays [1,2,3] and [10,20,30] would return [1,10,2,20,3,30]. Any help would be great, thanks.

This is what I have right now:

```
public int [] alternate(int [] a, int [] b){

int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length]

for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i + 2){

    c[i] = a[i];

    c[i + 1] = b[i];
}

return c;
```

Comment: `return IntStream.range(0, a.length).flatMap(i -> IntStream.of(a[i], b[i])).toArray();`

Comment: You should also say what's the current output (loop forever)

Comment: Hint: What does `i+2` do? Does that modify `i`?

Comment: What if these 2 arrays don't have the same length? Just put whatever is leftover at the end of the new array?

Comment: HINT #1: `for (...; i + 2)` doesn't actually change `i`.  Hint #2: assuming you fix the first problem, the first two iterations of the loop effectively do this: 1) `c[0] = a[0]; c[1] = b[0]` (so far so good); 2) `c[2] = a[2]; c[3] = b[2]` (WRONG!).  What happened to `a[1]` and `b[1]`?

Comment: I think the i + 2 is incorrect. I'm trying to make it so I can loop through the two given arrays and place alternating values into a new array. I believe I have to assume the arrays are of the same length

Comment: yeah I know I need c[2] = a[1], c[3] = b[1], c[4] = a[2], and c[5] = b[2]. How do I write that? I'm not sure how I change it to that after having c[i] = a[i] initially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Missing semicolon
2. Increment only to length of `a` - **assume a and b are same size**
3. Have counter to keep track of where new elements are inserted, or use idea as per @ErwinBolwidt
4. increment `i` normally
5. Note to self to test code before posting

So

```
public static int [] alternate(int [] a, int [] b){

    int[] c = new int[a.length + b.length];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

        c[counter++] = a[i];
        c[counter++] = b[i];
        // or
        //c[2 * i] = a[i];
        //c[2 * i + 1] = b[i];
    }

    return c; 
}
```

### Main Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,2,3} ;
    int[] b = {10,20,30} ;
    int[] test = alternate(a,b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
}
```

### Console Output:

> [1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30]

Comment: Possible alternative: rather than having a variable `counter`, use `2*i` and `2*i+1` as indices into `c`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt A lot better way, I need more coffee

Comment: @ScaryWombat : Would you mind reviewing and possibly upvoting my Java-8 based answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

If `a` and `b` arrays are not of same length, you can use the following method

```
public static int[] alternate(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int min, max;
    int count = 0;
    min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    max = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    int c[] = new int[min+max];

    for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        if(i<min) {
            c[count++] = a[i];
            c[count++] = b[i];
        }else {
            if(a.length==min) {
                c[count++] = b[i];  
            }else {
                c[count++] = a[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

**Main test**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4} ;
    int[] b = {10,20,30} ;
    int[] test = alternate(a,b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
}
```

**Output:**

[1, 10, 2, 20, 3, 30, 4]